# How to rotate image without storyboard?

Tags: rotation, windows-phone-8

I want to rotate the object not using story board.. in story board have from and to property it's easy. But i want first time click rotate that time rotate 90 deg at the same time click rotate rotate 180, and so on till 360....... simply i want each time of you click rotate that time rotate 90 deg....
I wnat this type of screen for each time of click rotate button......
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

please help me....

Thanks In Advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RotateTransform: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

In your code you can use it like this:

```
((RotateTransform)YourImageObjectName.RenderTransform).Angle = x;
```